# jQuery mobile redirects after page loads

Tags: redirect, jquery-mobile

I want to make a redirection with jQuery mobile right just after the page loads.
Something like this

```
<?php
... some php stuff here
?>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
<script>
        $.mobile.changePage("index.php");
</script>
```

But nothing happens...

Thanks!

Comment: Please try with my answer `script` is jquery mobile and redirect next page.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens because jQueryMobile hasn't done it's magic yet.

Try:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
      $.mobile.changePage("index.php");
});
```

You could also try some of the events listed at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

**Edited following comment:**
The following works as expected for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
            $.mobile.changePage("#pageTwo");
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="firstPageId" data-role="page">
        Page One
        </div>
        <div id="pageTwo" data-role="page">
        Page Two
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still seeing undefined.
I'm using this code
[code]
<html> 
  <head> 
        <title>My Page</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <div id="firstPageId">

    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).bind('pageinit', function() { $.mobile.changePage("index.php"); });
    </script>
</html>
[/code]

Comment: I can see it  in the body, but don't know where it comes from. It works fine, but when I try to print it with php... undefined. This is my code

if ($_POST) {
        mredirect("main.php");
         ...
function mredirect($link) {
    echo "...
        <script>
        $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
            $.mobile.changePage('link');
        });
        </script>
    </head>";
}

Comment: for now, I'm using header("location: page.php"), but Id like to use jquery mobile redirection... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain ol' JavaScript for this, you don't need jQuery:

```
window.location = "index.php";
```

To do it after the page loads, add a `$(document).ready()` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   window.location = "index.php";
});
```

Comment: I'd love to, but i only get 'undefined'. I want to use the redirection without using rel='external' in the jQuery link. Thanks

Comment: I don't follow what one has to do with the other. The JS redirect is independent of the stylesheet; maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you seeing `undefined` when you try `window.location`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's because of jUqery mobile I suppose. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to end of your page and before `</body>` tag,

```
<script>
  $(window).load("index.php", function() {
     // stuff or not
  });
</script>
```

**I hope help you. :)**

Answer (score 0):

Try, adding your page-id in the script with .live, something like this:

```
 $('#mainpage').live('pageinit', function (event) {
    alert("hi");
    //$.mobile.changePage("index.php");

});
```

Here is the full example: http://jsfiddle.net/KyKFE/

On the other hand, you can also use just plain javascript function or php (if .php page) to do the redirection. They are many different ways to do this.